# PHP string array displaying only the last result

Tags: php

Need help in displaying only the last array from the following code:

```
 $string = "localhost/project/vanilla_2/index.php?p=/discussions/MostCommented";
 /* Use tab and newline as tokenizing characters as well  */
 $tok = strtok($string, "/");

 while ($tok !== false) {
  echo "Word=$tok<br />";
    $tok = strtok("/");
```

as of now I am getting the following result:

```
  Word=localhost
  Word=project
  Word=vanilla_2
  Word=index.php?p=
  Word=discussions
  Word=MostCommented
```

Question:
How to get only the last result? (MostCommented)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are trying to get last string from URL. Check the following lines

```
$string = "localhost/project/vanilla_2/index.php?p=/discussions/MostCommented";
$explode_str = explode("/", $string);
echo end($explode_str);
```

Comment: I think `end($explode)` should be `end($explode_str)`

Comment: Yes works like a charm, thanks :) you both are a legend!